# AIR save .h264 video locally

Tags: actionscript-3, video, actionscript, air, h.264

I made an app that saves a video to the users desktop directory, but the encoder I'm using writes flv files. These get to be huge really quickly. At 640x360, a 20 second clip is about 20mb.

I'm using this encoder: 
http://flasheng.blogspot.com/2011/03/updated-flv-encoder-35x-faster-with.html

The alchemy option is super fast for writing files, but I think that means that it won't work on Macs. Is that right?

Anyway, I'd like to find a way to write compressed video files (to h264 or whatever). I tried running all of the frames through jpg encoding before writing them to the file, but that didn't make a dent in the file size.

I noticed that the NetStream class can save videos as .h264, but it requires them to be streamed to a server, and I need it to save locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you know C, you could make an [Actionscript Native Extension](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSb464b1207c184b14-70ccb6bd12937b4f2d6-8000.html) that makes use of the [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) library to encode the video.